# Css aligning/scroll bar problem

Tags: css, firefox, xhtml, scrollbar

yes another problem with this scroll bar

alright so I started the website over again that was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590658/html-css-website-showing-a-scroll-bar-which-doesnt-go-anywhere)

and I am having problems with this scroll bar again

alright so all I have is a single image in a div tag

```
<div align="center" id="SuggestionBox">
<a href="?PageN=2"><img src="images/SuggestionBox.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

this code displays right but

when I make the browser window small enough that the full image can not be seen it doesn't give me a scroll bar ***to*** see the whole image

hopefully this makes sense
I am using firefox

EDIT:

I tried overflow:scroll and it did not work

this was the outcome

[image]

and this happened in the middle of the page

I also tried 'overflow:scroll' on the body of the page through css and all it did was show disabled scroll bars that did not change no matter the size of the browser

also some people are a bit confused
so
this picture might help
[image]

notice how the image is not fully shown

well, I want there to be scroll bars in case the user wants to see the whole image

but they're not appearing

also here is all my css code:

```
body
{
background-image:url("images/background.jpg");
}
a:hover
{
color:#FF0000;
}
table
{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#SuggestionBox
{
position:relative;
right:375px;
}
```

### thanks

Good ***Luck***
get it?

Comment: What's your CSS. I can't do much without CSS. Also, `?PageN=2` isn't a valid URL. I'd change that...

Comment: @Blender actually ?PageN=2 is a valid URL, it basically is like saying this: currentpage.php?PageN=2

Comment: Thanks for posting your CSS.  I'm not sure what the purpose of the `#SuggestionBox` div is, but see if my update is helpful.

Comment: I've hit a little breakthrough... that this happens with everything including applets (I checked) now I know it has to do with the css or just the way the browser interprets it

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding your question, but it looks like your problem is that you've disabled scrolling in the `body` but would like the `div` to scroll.  @lukiffer's answer is right.  When you resize your browser, however, the scrolling `div`, which is a fixed size, isn't overflowing because its content still fits.

Are you wanting your "SuggestionBox" div to anchor to the page so that it resizes along with the page?  That would enable it to change sizes as the browser does and thus add scroll bars when its content doesn't fit:

```
#SuggestionBox
{
    position: absolute;

    /* Change these to establish where to place the div.  All zeroes 
       means it fills its whole container */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**Update**:

I don't get what `#SuggestionBox` is supposed to *be*.  If you're just wanting a centered image link, you could get rid of the `div` and just have this as your markup:

```
<a id="SuggestionBox"></a>
```

And for that `<a/>`, you could have the following CSS:

```
#SuggestionBox {
    display: block;
    width: 100px; /* Or whatever the width is */
    height: 100px; /* Or whatever the height is */
    background-image: url(images/SuggestionBox.jpg);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If your reason for having the div was to give your link a right margin of 375px, your CSS could have the margin set to `0 375px 0 auto` instead.

If you use this simple HTML/CSS, your body should be able to scroll normally (unless you have other CSS or HTML that you haven't posted that's breaking it).

Comment: I am simply creating a link which is the picture the actual problem is that the browser doesn't show a scrollbar when the window is too small to show the whole picture

Comment: also when I use the code that you gave me it works, but when I re-size the window the image stays and doesn't move out of the screen the point of aligning everything to the center was so nothing would collide, doing this, at the end, when I finish my site, a bunch of things wil collide, sorry I know how picky I am with this

Comment: What do you mean by saying that things will collide?  Are you wanting the image link to not be dynamically centered but to have a fixed margin?  If so, you could change the `margin` property to the fixed margins you'd like.

Comment: no, I do want it dynamically centered the only problem with your code... well. my goal in this website is for everything to be centered, and nothing colides, what I mean by this is, for instance this image and maybe a table don't come together. when this happens they mush together and it is very unappealing When I get a change I will post the site online for you to see..... by the way, thanks for the dedication in this question

Answer (score 0):

```
div#SuggestionBox { overflow:scroll; }
```